# Hiding url path in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am building a route in angular as show below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path:'**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

But when I open the webpage like http://localhost:4200/, it redirects to http://localhost:4200/home, which is the expected behavior, but I want to hide the /home at the end. Please dont be limited to this example only, this is only a simple scenario. Is there any way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense, just route path "" to HomeComponent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, of course. In your code, if you navigate to a particular component, you can then use this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/planning/capplanning'], {
      skipLocationChange: true,
    });
```

Comment: What about from the home page like lets say I just input http://localhost:4200/ but it should go to /home but not show it. Any idea

Comment: What about from the home page itself like I go to 4200/ but it should go to home component but not show /home over there. Any idea